# Why is Mathematica getting this modular root wrong?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

First, note that $4^{96}\equiv 96 \pmod {100}$.

*Mathematica* claims that `PowerMod[96, 1/96, 100]` has no integer solutions.

Even more obviously wrong, I get `{}` for

```
Solve[4^96 == x^96, Modulus -> 100]
```

which obviously has at least one solution (4).

Is this a known bug? Can I work around it somehow?

EDIT: I'm on *Mathematica* 9.0.1, running on OSX 10.10 Yosemite developer beta. Perhaps that could be the cause of this issue for me (also, mathematica crashes whenever I try to paste.).

Comment: Yes, I think this is a bug in `PowerMod`, although your second example doesn't give a wrong result for me (version 8.0.4).

Comment: I have had that crash before, too. It seems that it can be avoided if you copy from *Mathematica* `as plain text` (see the `Edit` menu under `Copy as...`).

Comment: I removed the version-9 tag because for the current version we don't need a special tag. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: Will investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Solve[4^96 == x^96, Modulus -> 100]
Solve[x^96 == 96, x, Modulus -> 100]
PowerModList[96, 1/96, 100]

(*
{{x -> 4}, {x -> 22}, {x -> 28}, {x -> 46}, {x -> 54}, {x -> 72}, {x -> 78}, {x -> 96}}
{{x -> 4}, {x -> 22}, {x -> 28}, {x -> 46}, {x -> 54}, {x -> 72}, {x -> 78}, {x -> 96}}
{4,22,28,46,54,72,78,96}
*)
```

Comment: Are you on mathematica 9?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat: Yes.

Comment: Did you try with PowerMod instead of PowerModList?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat: No. You asked for a work-around. I gave you one. I have not used `PowerMod` for years, no reason to, `PowerModList` is equivalent for non-Nth-root use, and gives complete results for Nth-root, so once it left being experimental (pre V6), I use it. I suspect this may be a bug in `PowerMod` - that function has existed, unchanged AFAIK, since V1.

Comment: I did switch to using PowerModList and have not run into this problem again, so now that you mention it I wonder why I still care about the PowerMid issue.

Answer (score 2):

It works on a Mac with v9.0.1

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

```
pml = PowerModList[96, 1/96, 100]
```

> {4, 22, 28, 46, 54, 72, 78, 96}

```
And @@ (Mod[#^96, 100] === PowerMod[#, 96, 100] === 96 & /@ pml)
```

> True

```
pml === (x /. Solve[4^96 == x^96, Modulus -> 100])
```

> True

Comment: I have the exact same version - it works for me with `PowerModList` but not `PowerMod`.